# How to work with CSV data in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and have been working with data that looks like this

```
  buzzard = [{
    "year": "1997",
    "population": "14500"
  }, {
    "year": "2006",
    "population": "37600"
  }, {
    "year": "2013",
    "population": "68000"
  }, ];

  redkite = [{
    "year": "1997",
    "population": "160"
  }, {
    "year": "2006",
    "population": "431"
  }, {
    "year": "2013",
    "population": "1600"
  },];

 ....
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hellococomo/nx92ek2n/2/) with that data I have created a menu for each species, which on a click event transitions between the population data. I now want to start working with CSV data but am unsure how to go about this

```
species,year,population
Buzzard,1997,14500
Buzzard,2006,37600
Buzzard,2013,68000
Red Kite,1997,160
Red Kite,2006,431
Red Kite,2013,1600
Sparrowhawk,1997,32000
Sparrowhawk,2006,21000
Sparrowhawk,2013,35000
```

I have tried using d3.nest() but am having trouble getting to the data. So I want to know if its possible to use this data to make the same chart I originally did, and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to nest your data b'coz you using csv.

You can use filter instead.

```
   d3.select('#opts')
     .on('change', function() {
       var selected = d3.select(this).property('value');
       //filter the data which has this value
       var cd = data.filter(function(d) {
         return (selected.toLowerCase() == d.species.toLowerCase())
       });
       updateLegend(cd);
     });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZepNMIocFEEGaidR0XC?p=preview)

**EDIT**

First get unique names for select box from your data.

```
   data.forEach(function(d) {
     if (uniqueNames.indexOf(d.species) < 0)
       uniqueNames.push(d.species)
   });
```

Then make select using that:

```
   list.append("select").selectAll("option")
     .data(uniqueNames)
     .enter().append("option")
     .attr("value", function(d) {
       return d;
     })
     .text(function(d) {
       return d;
     });
```

On change:

```
   list
     .on('change', function() {
       var selected = d3.select(this).select("select").property("value");
       console.log(selected)
       //filter the data which has this value
       var cd = data.filter(function(d) {
         return (selected == d.species)
       });
       updateLegend(cd);
     });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0NVhGq5ZacDAG7TpihbE?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hero! Thank you so much

Comment: Should this also work if I am creating the dropdown dynamically in d3? I've added it here http://plnkr.co/edit/7LZKa4yruUpwmgg8Cuxi?p=info but am now getting lots of repeat menu items, which is why I thought I needed to nest. Sorry, I know this wasn't the original question!

Comment: check my answer in teh **EDIT**

Comment: Sorry, I was off. This is a terrific explanation, I didn't know you could get data that way! You've saved me days, thank you